# wso2 identity server validate Scopes for a jwt token from Resource Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am able to validate JWT Token via /services/OAuth2TokenValidationService from resource server.
Now I want to validate this against a particular Scope?I want to know this JWT is valid against a particular scope. OAuth Introspection Endpoint is not available in production yet.So please suggest me some other ideas

Answer (score 0):

OAuth Introspection API will be available with IS 5.3.0. You can try the introspection endpoint with [IS 5.3.0-beta](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/download/v5.3.0-beta/wso2is-5.3.0-beta.zip) for now.

You can find documentation related to the introspection endpoint [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Invoke+the+OAuth+Introspection+Endpoint).

Comment: is it just a REST version of the wsdl service Oauth2TokenValidationService? Or does it have additional functionalities

Comment: it's not a REST layer on top of the SOAP service. Rather it's the implementation of https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7662 specification